# Angular promise in state resolve empty

Tags: angularjs

I am not familiar with Angular at all and kind off in a deep end situation. Please forgive the ignorance and be kind. We have the following state:

```
.state('busList', {
        //after button
        url: '/bus',
        templateUrl: 'app/bus/search/list.html',
        controller: 'BusListCtrl',
        resolve: {
            oneway: function ($stateParams, Vuka, $log) {
                return searchBusTrip($stateParams.departureLocation.locationId, $stateParams.arrivalLocation.locationId, $stateParams.departureDate, $stateParams.numPassengers).$promise;
            },
            returns: function ($stateParams, Vuka) {
                return searchBusTrip($stateParams.arrivalLocation.locationId, $stateParams.departureLocation.locationId, $stateParams.returnDate, $stateParams.numPassengers).$promise;
            }
        },
        params: {
            departureLocation: undefined,
            arrivalLocation: undefined,
            departureDate: undefined,
            returnDate: undefined,
            numPassengers: undefined,
            oneWay: false
        }
    })
```

The searchBusTrip as follows:

```
searchBusTrip: function (p_departureLocationId, p_destinationLocationId, p_departureDate, p_numberOfPassengers) {
        var intercape_response = $http({
            //url: c_url_man + 'SearchBusTrip',
            url: c_url + 'SearchBusTrip',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                provider: 'Intercape',
                sessionId: guid(),
                departureLocationId: p_departureLocationId,
                destinationLocationId: p_destinationLocationId,
                departureDate: p_departureDate,
                numberOfPassengers: p_numberOfPassengers
            }
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            response.data.tripSegments;
            angular.forEach(response.data.tripSegments, function (tripSegment) {
                var arrivalDateObj = new Date(tripSegment.arrivalDate);
                var departureDateObj = new Date(tripSegment.departureDate);
                tripSegment.timeSpace = Math.floor((((arrivalDateObj / 1000) - (departureDateObj / 1000)) / 3600));
                listings.push(tripSegment);
                //console.log(tripSegment.provider);
            });
          }).catch(function errorCallback(response) {
              //error
          }).finally(function() {
            alert(listings);
          }); return listings;
```

The alert giving listings is giving the correct populated result. However, this happens a few seconds after the new page started loading. Therefor I assume the return in the resolve of the state is empty. I have worked off this:

[How to force AngularJS resource resolution with ui-router](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-resolve-angularjs-resources-with-ui-router/)
I have tried returning the listings in the searchBusTrip function. I have tried to add the then & finally to the return in oneway and returns in the .state. I have tried to delay the stateChangeStart, and countless other options. I realise my lack of a proper understanding of Angular is the biggest problem.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello! Could you please create a [mcve]? Not only will this help you learn more about the source of the problem, but it will allow us to run your code and find the problem.

Comment: Function `searchBusTrip()` doesn't have any `return`. Also no need to use `$q.defer();` with `$http` since `$http` already returns a promise. You need to return that promise from the function

Comment: @4castle Yes, unfortunately this must be finished in the next 30mins.

Comment: @charlietfl I've done the edit as per above. It is still not working though. The page starts loading before the the function is finished.